# How to search for a file in one directory in google drive?

Tags: google-drive

I'm searching Google Drive for a particular term, but it's brining up many, many files. I know the name of the folder that the file resides in. Can I use it to help search for the file?

#### Example

For example, suppose the file name is foo, and the directory name is bar, and a search for 'foo' brings up far too many files to manually look through, then I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
foo infolder:bar
```

I tried a few things and nothing I did worked. Also looked at a few articles ([example](https://seosly.com/blog/google-drive-search-operators/)), but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Search Within Folder

---

**================

Right-Click Method

================**
In the Google Drive Web App you can right-click on the folder **bar** and select the menu item `Search within bar` then put **foo** as the search term.  Optionally, make any other customizations then click `SEARCH`

[image: menu]

[image: search]
 
 
**===================

Search Options Method

===================**
You can alternatively click on the `Show search options` button. Then, in the `search options` dialog box, specify **bar** as the `Location` and **foo <sup>1</sup>** as the `Item name`.

**<sup>1</sup>** A search for **foo** is equivalent to ***foo***. i.e. **foo** anywhere in the title.

[image: search options dialog]